# custome hook, Too many re renders React Limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

When I add a product to the cart I check if it already exist in my cart if exist I just update quantity of that product, if it doesn't exist I send it to the cart

the action increaseQuantity upate the quantity and the action addToCart send a new product to the redux state, it works perfectl When I click the button it pass product, quantity, color and size by params to the function like this and work

```
 AddOrUpdateCard(product, 1, "red", "xS") //clicked button

  const AddOrUpdateCard = (product, quantity, color, size) => {
    if(product){
      const filteredproduct = cartData.find(singleProduct => singleProduct.id === product.id);
      if(filteredproduct){
        // if product is not in cart update quantity
        increaseQuantity(filteredproduct, addToast)
      }else{
        //si el producto is not in the cart add it
        addToCart(
            product,
            addToast,
            quantity,
            color,
            size
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to extract the logic of this component in a costume hook to use it in other component, I have created my hook like this, however I dont know how to use it, I mport it in my component, It shows an error: Too many re renders React kimits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop, I am pretty sure it is because the way I am calling the hook (I am begginer with react), please check the component with and without the custome hook further down, how could I use custome hook in my component. thanks for your help

```
//Aactualizar redux sin conectar
const useCartQuantity = (selectedProduct) => {
  const { addToast } = useToasts();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartData = useSelector((state) => state.cartData);

  if (selectedProduct?.product) {
    const productIncart = cartData.find(
      (singleProduct) => singleProduct.id === selectedProduct?.product?.id
    );
    if (productIncart && Object.entries(productIncart).length > 0) {
      dispatch(increaseQuantity(productIncart, addToast));
    } else {
      dispatch(
        addToCart(
          selectedProduct?.product,
          addToast,
          selectedProduct?.quantity,
          selectedProduct?.color,
          selectedProduct?.size
        )
      );
    }
  }
};

export default useCartQuantity;
```

this is my component without the customed hook (it works well and update the quantity if the product is already in cart, if it is not, send the product to the cart)

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { getDiscountPrice } from "../../helpers/product";
import Rating from "./sub-components/ProductRating";
import ProductModal from "./ProductModal";
import {addProductToWishlist} from '../../utils/services/wishlistService';
import {deleteFromWishlist} from '../../redux/actions/wishlistActions';
import { addToCart } from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { deleteFromCart} from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { increaseQuantity } from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import useCartQuantity from "../../utils/hooks/useCartQuantity";
import Product from "../../pages/shop-product/Product";



const ProductGridListSingle = ({
  product,
  currency,
  addToCart,
  addToWishlist,
  addToCompare,
  cartItem,
  wishlistItem,
  compareItem,
  sliderClassName,
  spaceBottomClass,
  cartData,
  deleteFromCart,
  ieaseQuantity,
}) => {

  const discountedPrice = getDiscountPrice(product.price, product.discount);
  const finalProductPrice = +(product.price).toFixed(0);
  const finalDiscountedPrice = discountedPrice ? discountedPrice.toFixed(0) : "";
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false)

  const { addToast } = useToasts();


  const AddOrUpdateCard = (product, quantity, color, size) => {
    if(product){
      const filteredproduct = cartData.find(singleProduct => singleProduct.id === product.id);
      if(filteredproduct){
        // if product is not in cart update quantity
        increaseQuantity(filteredproduct, addToast)
      }else{
        //si el producto is not in the cart add it
        addToCart(
            product,
            addToast,
            quantity,
            color,
            size
        )
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        className={`col-xl-4 col-sm-6 ${
          sliderClassName ? sliderClassName : ""
        }`}
      >
        <div
          className={`product-wrap ${spaceBottomClass ? spaceBottomClass : ""}`}
        >
          <div className="product-img">
            <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/product/" + product.id}>
              <img
                className="default-img"
                src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + product.image[0]}
                alt=""
              />
              {product.image.length > 1 ? (
                <img
                  className="hover-img"
                  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + product.image[1]}
        
                />
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Link>
            {product.discount || product.new ? (
              <div className="product-img-badges">
                {product.discount ? (
                  <span className="pink">-{product.discount}%</span>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {product.new ? <span className="purple">Nuevo</span> : ""}
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}

            <div className="product-action">
              <div className="pro-same-action pro-wishlist">
                <button product={product}
                  className={wishlistItem !== undefined ? "active" : ""}
                  disabled={wishlistItem !== undefined}
                  title={
                    wishlistItem !== undefined
                      ? "Agregado a lista de deseos"
                      : "Agregar a lista de deseos"
                  }
                  onClick={()=>{
                    addProductToWishlist(product)
                    addToWishlist(product, addToast)
                  }}         
                >
                  <i className="pe-7s-like" />
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="pro-same-action pro-cart">
                {product.affiliateLink ? (
                  <a
                    href={product.affiliateLink}
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    {" "}
                    Comprar{" "}
                  </a>
                ) : product.variation && product.variation.length >= 1 ? (
                  <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/product/${product.id}`}>
                    Ver más
                  </Link>
                ) : product.stock && product.stock > 0 ? (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => addToCart(product, addToast)}
                    className={
                      cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                        ? "active"
                        : ""
                    }
                    disabled={cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0}
                    title={
                      cartItem !== undefined ? "Agregado al carrito" : "Agregar al carrito"
                    }
                  >
                    {" "}
                    <i className="pe-7s-cart"></i>{" "}
                    {cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                      ? "Added"
                      : "Agregar al carrito"}
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <button disabled className="active">
                    Sin Stock
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="pro-same-action pro-quickview">
                  <button onClick={() =>
                   AddOrUpdateCard(product, 1, "red", "xS")
                }>
                  <i class="pe-7s-shopbag"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        
            <div className="col-xl-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
              <div className="shop-list-content">
                <h3>
                  <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/product/" + product.id}>
                    {product.name}
                  </Link>
                </h3>
                <div className="product-list-price">
                  {discountedPrice !== null ? (
                    <Fragment>
                      <span>
                        {currency.currencySymbol + finalDiscountedPrice}
                      </span>{" "}
                      <span className="old">
                        {currency.currencySymbol + finalProductPrice}
                      </span>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <span>{currency.currencySymbol + finalProductPrice} </span>
                  )}
                </div>
                {product.rating && product.rating > 0 ? (
                  <div className="rating-review">
                    <div className="product-list-rating">
                      <Rating ratingValue={product.rating} />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {product.shortDescription ? (
                  <p>{product.shortDescription}</p>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}

                <div className="shop-list-actions d-flex align-items-center">
                  <div className="shop-list-btn btn-hover">
                    {product.affiliateLink ? (
                      <a
                        href={product.affiliateLink}
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        target="_blank"
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Comprar{" "}
                      </a>
                    ) : product.variation && product.variation.length >= 1 ? (
                      <Link
                        to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/product/${product.id}`}
                      >
                        Ver más
                      </Link>
                    ) : product.stock && product.stock > 0 ? (
                      <button
                        onClick={() => addToCart(product, addToast)}
                        className={
                          cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                            ? "active"
                            : ""
                        }
                        disabled={
                          cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                        }
                        title={
                          cartItem !== undefined
                            ? "Agregado al carrito"
                            : "Agregar al carrito"
                        }
                      >
                        {" "}
                        <i className="pe-7s-cart"></i>{" "}
                        {cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                          ? "Added"
                          : "Agregar al carrito"}
                      </button>
                    ) : (
                      <button disabled className="active">
                        Sin Stock
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </div>

                  <div className="shop-list-wishlist ml-10">
                    <button
                      className={wishlistItem !== undefined ? "active" : ""}
                      disabled={wishlistItem !== undefined}
                      title={
                        wishlistItem !== undefined
                          ? "Agregado a lista de deseos"
                          : "Agregar a lista de deseos"
                      }
                      onClick={() => addToWishlist(product, addToast)}
                    >
                      <i className="pe-7s-like" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="shop-list-compare ml-10">
                    <button
                      className={compareItem !== undefined ? "active" : ""}
                      disabled={compareItem !== undefined}
                      title={
                        compareItem !== undefined
                          ? "Added to compare"
                          : "Add to compare"
                      }
                      onClick={() => addToCompare(product, addToast)}
                    >
                      <i className="pe-7s-shuffle" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* product modal */}
 
    </Fragment>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cartData: state.cartData,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    deleteFromWishlist: (item) => {
      dispatch(deleteFromWishlist(item));
    },
    addToCart: ( item, addToast, quantityCount, selectedProductColor, selectedProductSize) => {
      dispatch(addToCart( item, addToast, quantityCount, selectedProductColor, selectedProductSize)
      );
    },
    deleteFromCart: (productToDelete) => {
      dispatch(deleteFromCart(productToDelete));
    },
    increaseQuantity: (item, addToast) => {
      dispatch(increaseQuantity(item, addToast));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductGridListSingle);
```

This is my component with my custome hook

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { getDiscountPrice } from "../../helpers/product";
import Rating from "./sub-components/ProductRating";
import ProductModal from "./ProductModal";
import {addProductToWishlist} from '../../utils/services/wishlistService';
import {deleteFromWishlist} from '../../redux/actions/wishlistActions';
import { addToCart } from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { deleteFromCart} from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { increaseQuantity } from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import useCartQuantity from "../../utils/hooks/useCartQuantity";
import Product from "../../pages/shop-product/Product";




const ProductGridListSingle = ({
  product,
  currency,
  addToCart,
  addToWishlist,
  addToCompare,
  cartItem,
  wishlistItem,
  compareItem,
  sliderClassName,
  spaceBottomClass,
  cartData,
  deleteFromCart,
  increaseQuantity,
}) => {

  const discountedPrice = getDiscountPrice(product.price, product.discount);
  const finalProductPrice = +(product.price).toFixed(0);
  const finalDiscountedPrice = discountedPrice ? discountedPrice.toFixed(0) : "";
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false)
  //CLICKED PRODUCT
  const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState({})


  const { addToast } = useToasts();
    const AddOrUpdateCard = (product, quantity, color, size) => {
      setSelectedProduct({
        product,
        quantity,
        color,
        size,
      })
    }

    //CUSTOME HOOK
    useCartQuantity(selectedProduct);

  
   
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        className={`col-xl-4 col-sm-6 ${
          sliderClassName ? sliderClassName : ""
        }`}
      >
        <div
          className={`product-wrap ${spaceBottomClass ? spaceBottomClass : ""}`}
        >
          <div className="product-img">
            <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/product/" + product.id}>
              <img
                className="default-img"
                src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + product.image[0]}
                alt=""
              />
              {product.image.length > 1 ? (
                <img
                  className="hover-img"
                  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + product.image[1]}
                  alt=""
                />
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Link>
            {product.discount || product.new ? (
              <div className="product-img-badges">
                {product.discount ? (
                  <span className="pink">-{product.discount}%</span>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {product.new ? <span className="purple">Nuevo</span> : ""}
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}

            <div className="product-action">
              <div className="pro-same-action pro-wishlist">
                <button product={product}
                  className={wishlistItem !== undefined ? "active" : ""}
                  disabled={wishlistItem !== undefined}
                  title={
                    wishlistItem !== undefined
                      ? "Agregado a lista de deseos"
                      : "Agregar a lista de deseos"
                  }
                  onClick={()=>{
                    addProductToWishlist(product)
                    addToWishlist(product, addToast)
                  }}         
                >
               
                  <i className="pe-7s-like" />
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="pro-same-action pro-cart">
                {product.affiliateLink ? (
                  <a
                    href={product.affiliateLink}
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    {" "}
                    Comprar{" "}
                  </a>
                ) : product.variation && product.variation.length >= 1 ? (
                  <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/product/${product.id}`}>
                    Ver más
                  </Link>
                ) : product.stock && product.stock > 0 ? (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => addToCart(product, addToast)}
                    className={
                      cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                        ? "active"
                        : ""
                    }
                    disabled={cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0}
                    title={
                      cartItem !== undefined ? "Agregado al carrito" : "Agregar al carrito"
                    }
                  >
                    {" "}
                    <i className="pe-7s-cart"></i>{" "}
                    {cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                      ? "Added"
                      : "Agregar al carrito"}
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <button disabled className="active">
                    Sin Stock
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="pro-same-action pro-quickview">
                  <button onClick={() =>
                   AddOrUpdateCard(product, 1, "red", "xS")
                }>
                  <i class="pe-7s-shopbag"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        
            <div className="col-xl-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
              <div className="shop-list-content">
                <h3>
                  <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/product/" + product.id}>
                    {product.name}
                  </Link>
                </h3>
                <div className="product-list-price">
                  {discountedPrice !== null ? (
                    <Fragment>
                      <span>
                        {currency.currencySymbol + finalDiscountedPrice}
                      </span>{" "}
                      <span className="old">
                        {currency.currencySymbol + finalProductPrice}
                      </span>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <span>{currency.currencySymbol + finalProductPrice} </span>
                  )}
                </div>
                {product.rating && product.rating > 0 ? (
                  <div className="rating-review">
                    <div className="product-list-rating">
                      <Rating ratingValue={product.rating} />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {product.shortDescription ? (
                  <p>{product.shortDescription}</p>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}

                <div className="shop-list-actions d-flex align-items-center">
                  <div className="shop-list-btn btn-hover">
                    {product.affiliateLink ? (
                      <a
                        href={product.affiliateLink}
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        target="_blank"
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Comprar{" "}
                      </a>
                    ) : product.variation && product.variation.length >= 1 ? (
                      <Link
                        to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/product/${product.id}`}
                      >
                        Ver más
                      </Link>
                    ) : product.stock && product.stock > 0 ? (
                      <button
                        onClick={() => addToCart(product, addToast)}
                        className={
                          cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                            ? "active"
                            : ""
                        }
                        disabled={
                          cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                        }
                        title={
                          cartItem !== undefined
                            ? "Agregado al carrito"
                            : "Agregar al carrito"
                        }
                      >
                        {" "}
                        <i className="pe-7s-cart"></i>{" "}
                        {cartItem !== undefined && cartItem.quantity > 0
                          ? "Added"
                          : "Agregar al carrito"}
                      </button>
                    ) : (
                      <button disabled className="active">
                        Sin Stock
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </div>

                  <div className="shop-list-wishlist ml-10">
                    <button
                      className={wishlistItem !== undefined ? "active" : ""}
                      disabled={wishlistItem !== undefined}
                      title={
                        wishlistItem !== undefined
                          ? "Agregado a lista de deseos"
                          : "Agregar a lista de deseos"
                      }
                      onClick={() => addToWishlist(product, addToast)}
                    >
                      <i className="pe-7s-like" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="shop-list-compare ml-10">
                    <button
                      className={compareItem !== undefined ? "active" : ""}
                      disabled={compareItem !== undefined}
                      title={
                        compareItem !== undefined
                          ? "Added to compare"
                          : "Add to compare"
                      }
                      onClick={() => addToCompare(product, addToast)}
                    >
                      <i className="pe-7s-shuffle" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ProductGridListSingle.propTypes = {
  addToCart: PropTypes.func,
  addToCompare: PropTypes.func,
  addToWishlist: PropTypes.func,
  cartItem: PropTypes.object,
  compareItem: PropTypes.object,
  currency: PropTypes.object,
  product: PropTypes.object,
  sliderClassName: PropTypes.string,
  spaceBottomClass: PropTypes.string,
  wishlistItem: PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cartData: state.cartData,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    deleteFromWishlist: (item) => {
      dispatch(deleteFromWishlist(item));
    },
    addToCart: ( item, addToast, quantityCount, selectedProductColor, selectedProductSize) => {
      dispatch(addToCart( item, addToast, quantityCount, selectedProductColor, selectedProductSize)
      );
    },
    deleteFromCart: (productToDelete) => {
      dispatch(deleteFromCart(productToDelete));
    },
    increaseQuantity: (item, addToast) => {
      dispatch(increaseQuantity(item, addToast));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductGridListSingle);
```

this is the custome hook

```
import { addToCart } from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { increaseQuantity } from "../../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";

//Aactualizar redux sin conectar
const useCartQuantity = (selectedProduct) => {
  const { addToast } = useToasts();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartData = useSelector((state) => state.cartData);

  if (selectedProduct?.product) {
    const productIncart = cartData.find(
      (singleProduct) => singleProduct.id === selectedProduct?.product?.id
    );
    if (productIncart && Object.entries(productIncart).length > 0) {
      dispatch(increaseQuantity(productIncart, addToast));
    } else {
      dispatch(
        addToCart(
          selectedProduct?.product,
          addToast,
          selectedProduct?.quantity,
          selectedProduct?.color,
          selectedProduct?.size
        )
      );
    }
  }
};

export default useCartQuantity;
```